# System.Null pointer exception error on an empty line of code?

Tags: unit-test, failing-tests

I am getting below error in a test class when I want to save another class.

`System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object` at line 32

The problem is that I commented line 32, but was still getting the error on this line. Now even deleted the commented code from test class and left line 32 empty but still getting the same error on this line.

The code which I am saving is no thing to do with this test class. Anyone faced this situation?

Comment: `System.NullPointerException` is a runtime error, not a compilation error, how are you getting it from trying to save a class?

Comment: When new class/trigger is saving all/some test classes/methods are also executed. I am getting this error in test class @Namfuak

Comment: I'm curious how you have testmethods automatically launched upon saving an edited class. I didn't know you could do that.

Comment: @crop1645 they're editing directly in production via Force.com IDE. Can't say I recommend that process...

Comment: @sfdcfox oh jeez -- I never tried that and would have thought the IDE could detect and prevent that.  Makes doing diffs between prod and sandbox that much more fraught with danger as it is easy to inadvertently save the wrong resource as Eclipse doesn't give you much of a visual cue as to whether a resource is prod vs sandbox except in the title bar

Comment: @crop1645 - Tooling API allows modifying / saving classes directly to production. Metadata API block it.

Comment: @sfdcfox Yes, you are correct. I am editing this in production because I need a quick fix in production and there is a lot going on in sandbox due to which sandbox is very different from production even the current class is much different in sandbox than live. To deploy new changes from sandbox to live will take couple of weeks. So it is a temporary fix, that is why I wanted to do this in production directly.

Comment: @abdn , Check for correct class on which the line 32 is giving error. Are you absolutely sure you are commenting out correct class line 32?